# Rest store doesn't send request on server

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a grid and REST store (proxy type 'rest') with it. I need to send delete/put/post request to server, when changing store data.
Here is code of the store:

```
        this.store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {



        model:this.model,

        addCondition:function (key, value) {
            this.proxy.extraParams[key] = value;
            return this;
        },
        sorters:[
            {
                property:'NAME',
                direction:'ASC'
            }
        ],
        proxy:{

            storeId:'storemicorid',
            type:'rest',
            extraParams:{
                model:this.model
            },
            url:document.head.baseURI + 'rest',
            /*api:{ //tried this too
                read:document.head.baseURI + 'rest',
                create:document.head.baseURI + 'rest',
                destroy:document.head.baseURI + 'restd',
                update:document.head.baseURI + 'rest'
            },*/
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'data'

            },
            writer: {
                type: 'json',
                encode: true,
                root: 'data'
            },
            actionMethods:{
                create: "POST",
                destroy: "DELETE",
                read: "GET",
                update: "PUT"

            }



        }

    });
```

When I delete any record

```
clientgrid.store.remove(selection);
```

**there are no request to server**. Grid can load data, but doesn't call server. Tried **ajax** and **rest** store, tried change **writers**, **actionMethods**, **urls** and **api**... Can't find the reason.. Help please...

Comment: What if you call store.sync() manually?

Comment: When i call sync() after deleting item, it sends data of first record in the grid to the adress, that set in proxy settings. In json format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try to set the attribute `autoSync:true;`? Maybe it helps.

Comment: Okay, it was a try. Once it was working for me. You can check if the events are getting fired: `Ext.util.Observable.capture(this.store, function(e) { console.info(e);});` But i don't know how to use it without MVC ;-)

Comment: in console: remove, datachanged

Comment: So it's working... You said the first record in the grid is send to the address when you use `clientgrid.store.remove(selection);
`? When the first one is selected, then its correct when not check `selection`-Variable.

Comment: But how to send data to server, that I deleted something. Or updated? Or created? Standart restful store must do it automatically on the links, what I gave for it, and with actionMethods, that is defined (PUT,DELETE...). How I need to serve this actions?

Comment: usually it works automatically whenn you edit a row in the grid or add a row into the store by using store.add({MYDATA}). Here is a good Tutorial for Stores: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/guide/data.